# How to move a text input to the top in a input field?

Tags: html, css

I've recently started learning Html and Css and I'm trying to move the word **"Your Comment"** to the top in the input field.

```
https://prnt.sc/1k74619
```

```
<div class="comment">
<input placeholder="Your Comment" type="text" />
</div>
```

```
.comment input {
    width: 680px;
    height: 169;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    outline-color: #b5b5b5;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -115px;       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<INPUT>` tag is for single line text but `<TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>` tag is for multi line text.
**Useful link:** https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.comment input,
.comment textarea{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 680px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.comment textarea{
    height: 169px;
}
.comment input:focus,
.comment textarea:focus{
    border: 1px solid #32babe;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #32babe;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Commnet - in single line">
    <textarea placeholder="Your Comment - in multi lines"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do, if you want a larger multi line text input area `<textarea></textarea>` may suit your needs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

If you want to achieve the same effect you can try nesting the input field in a bordered `<div>` something like this perhaps:

https://codepen.io/iltg/pen/RwVemeB

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```css
textarea {
    font-size: .8rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="story" name="story"
          rows="5" cols="33">
Your comment
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's [floating label](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/). It would do the job very nicely.

Here's how you will do it:

```
<div class="form-floating">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="floatingTextarea"></textarea>
  <label for="floatingTextarea">Comments</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-field{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.comment input, .comment textarea {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 680px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.custom-field input:focus + .placeholder {
    top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-field">
    <input id="email-field" type="email">
    <label for="email-field" class="placeholder">Enter Email</label>
</div>
```